# Getting an OAuth Callback [C#]

Tags: c#, rest, web, oauth

I'm making a CLI that uses the Bit Bucket API and I am attempting to record both the oAuth token and the oAuth verifier. So far I've opened up a web browser to this hyperlink(as an example):

https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=4vyW6b49ZxcZDK64eY

This takes the user through an authentication process run by the vendor. How would I listen for the token and the verifier? So far I'm doing:

```
Process.Start(...)
```

and am lost as to how I'm supposed to listen for the callback without user intervention.

Comment: What type of application is this?

Comment: Command Line Application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this callback requires a REST endpoint you will need to host this endpoint.

To host a REST endpoint in your console application you will need to use OWIN. Which is a component for hosting websites/webapplications/REST apis in a self contained manner without the use of an external webserver (e.g. IIS).

Example on how to do this can be found here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api